# Get login status on the server side(C#)

Tags: c#, facebook

How can I get the login status of the user From the server in the ASP.NET?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408762/check-facebook-login-status-and-get-session-details-using-facebook-c-sharp-sdk

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about [Session Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms178581.aspx). And, if you are talking about state management, you can manage it client as well as server side. Just try to use client side because its quite light weight and can make an impressive client! The main benefit is to avoid load on server.

Comment: I am talking about viewstate , querystring and hiddenfield

Comment: Thanks for Your answer.I'm talking about the user state... Before I showed to a user a requested page, I have to hide some components.But it depends from his login status...If i will make it on the client, I will need to send page back to the server, make changes, that I need, and return the page...